# gameObject SetActive(false) is disabling all my child objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child, onmouseover, disable

I have two scripts a parent and a child. The parent script provides the On Mouseover method for the child to use if Input.("Fire1") is used. and then it SHOULD disable the collider the mouse is over and score a point. But I am having an error where if I click on one prefab collider with the child script attached, it will then disable all prefab game objects. how can I fix this so my child script only allows for one disabling of a prefab at a time?

**Parent Script**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CollectableParent : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    protected GameManager gameManager;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        gameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void OnMouseOver()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            gameManager.UpdateScore(5);
        }
    }

 
    

    
    
}
```

**ChildScript**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LevelOneJack : CollectableParent
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            OnMouseOver();
           
        }
        
    }
   


}
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now!

Answer (score 0):

so i removed the the child class if statement from the child class "Update" method and am instead calling the OnMoseOver method, in a override method. which works well, the objects now only get disabled one at a time. I figure the problem is that I was disabling the parent script there for disabling all children scripts and objects too.

the only issue I have now is, when I hover the moues over an object, it automatically fires the UpdateScore method, even though there is an If statement checking if Input is true before it does the action.  **Its because i had the if statement syntax wrong**

This is the updated child script

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class LevelOneJack : CollectableParent
 {
     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
 
     }
 
     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
 
       
     }
 
         public override void OnMouseOver()
          {
         if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
             base.OnMouseOver();
             gameManager.UpdateScore(5);
          }
 
      }
```